# angular2-datatable Pass event with extra parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-datatables

In angular2-datatable there's an implementation for sorting when click on the item on table head. For this we have to use DefaultSorter as:

```
<mfDefaultSorter [by]="sortByItem">{{ head }}</mfDefaultSorter>
```

the by attribute call the sortByItem method in which you can capture the event.

```
sortByItem(event) {
  return event._id;
}
```

I want to pass additional parameter with the exact event. I have tried using the ref variable but that doesn't work or you can say it doesn't fulfill what I want to achieve.

In order to see it for yourself, I have created this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-datatable

In the above mentioned example you can check `sortByWordLength` method. I want to pass the exact event with additional parameter.

**Additional Information:**

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

github: https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional parameter using [curried function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983) like below.

```
  <mfDefaultSorter [by]="sortByWordLength('abc')">City</mfDefaultSorter>
  ...
  public sortByWordLength = (b:string) => (a: any) => {
     console.log(a);
     console.log(b);
     return a.city.length;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-datatable-ldp4fg